# SQL error when trying to use sortOrder on Matrix related block (Craft 2)

Tags: matrix, relations, ordering, relatedto, sorting

I'm getting the following SQL error when trying to simply order related entries in a Matrix block. Anyway around this?

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'sortOrder' in order clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, ...

This is what's throwing the error:

```
{% set package = craft.entries({
relatedTo: block,
order: 'sortOrder'}) %}
```

Comment: Are you working in Craft 2 or Craft 3?

Comment: I'm using Craft 2. Updated the question.

Comment: I don't believe you need the `order: 'sortOrder'` it does that by default when you access related entries.  Here is another post that may be of help. https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/custom-order-related-entries/4657#4657

Comment: Thanks @aran but no, it's not obeying the sortOrder. I only seem to come across this issue on a related entry within a Matrix field block.

Answer (score 1):

So this was me being a bit of a numpty here. I was calling the field the wrong way. Doing the following obeys the sort order from the field:

```
{% for entry in block.hostingPackage %}
```